# Convert XDocument to Stream

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

How do I convert the XML in an XDocument to a MemoryStream, without saving anything to disk?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have a look at the [XDocument.WriteTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.writeto.aspx) method; e.g.:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
    xws.Indent = true;

    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, xws))
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Child",
                new XElement("GrandChild", "some content")
            )
        );
        doc.WriteTo(xw);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or .Save - but the example holds ;-p

Comment: @Marc What's the difference between WriteTo() and Save()?

Comment: @Daniel Fortunov: .Save provides more overloads, but all of these end up calling .WriteTo

Answer (score 49):

In .NET 4 and later, you can Save it to a `MemoryStream`:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(stream);
// Rewind the stream ready to read from it elsewhere
stream.Position = 0;
```

In .NET 3.5 and earlier, you would need to create an `XmlWriter` based on a `MemoryStream` and save to that, as shown in [dtb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750250).

Comment: I wonder if both approaches add \r\n and whitespace.  It would be great to have an easy option here (rather than overload the existing XmlWriter)

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement(C_ROOT,
        new XElement("Child")));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    doc.Save(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```