# Convert linq.Xelement to stream for XMLTextReader

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mocking

I am producing an XML file in my unit test using

```
Public Sub rssParserTest
   Dim Const rssUri as String = "rssTestFile.xml"
   Dim xmlFile = <rss version="2.0">
   ...
                 </rss>
   xmlFile.save(rssUri)

  rssParser(rssUri)
End Sub
```

and consuming the uri with an XMLTextReader

```
Public Sub rssParser(ByVal rssUri as string)
    Dim rssXml = New XmlTextReader(rssUri)
    rssXml.read
    ...
End Sub
```

I want to remove the unit test dependency on a physical file and use a stream instead but my efforts so far have come to nought. (Is this best practise?)

I am using NMock2 for mocking if I should be doing something with that.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than force an `XmlTextReader` via a stream, if you just nead an `XmlReader` you can just use [`XNode.CreateReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.createreader.aspx). That's a much simpler approach than saving to a stream, unless your API *forces* you to use a stream or an `XmlTextReader`.

Answer (score 0):

`xmlFile` is an `XDocument`, which can be saved into a `MemoryStream`, see the following SO question for details:

- [Convert XDocument to Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750198/87698) (The code samples are in C#, but the .NET API methods used are the same.)

You can then make your method accept a generic `Stream`, which can then be a `MemoryStream` (in the unit test) or a `FileStream`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @sschaef: Are you sure? He asks how he can convert his `xmlFile` variable into a stream without having to write it to disk (see also the question title), and the linked SO question answers that question. Granted, it's not a very *good* answer (I was probably in a hurry back then; it could be extended by a more detailed explanation and a summary of the relevant parts of the linked question), but it does answer the question. Do you still disagree?

Comment: Ok, very strictly speaking it does provide an answer. But firstly, the linked question is about C#, which means that he solution can not directly moved to VB.NET. Secondly, even than it is a link only answer. In my opinion this makes it more a comment for a hint on how to solve the question.

Comment: @sschaef: I've added some context.