# How can I turn an XDocument into a Stream?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, stream, linq-to-xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert XDocument to Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750198/convert-xdocument-to-stream)

The question speaks for itself - how do I turn an `XDocument` into a `Stream` without saving anything to disk?